# How do you allow outbound Internet Access to Power BI Gateway?

Tags: azure, powerbi

How can you allow outbound Internet access to Power BI from a VM running Power BI Gateway? Right now it seems that Microsoft doesn't have a service tag for Power BI and I'm avoiding allowing explicit access outbound. Is there some way to create an augmented/custom service tag within the NSG of the VM if I have the public IP addresses?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft ended up providing the service tag for general availability a few months after I had posted this question.